# How to understand the notation behind the standarded residuals?

Tags: notation

I don't understand my lecture notes. It states that standarded residuals is by definition
$$R_i=\dfrac{y_i-\hat{y}_i}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2 }}$$
I understand that I can compute $\hat{y}$ by the ordinary least-squares method. But as we have $i$ used as a subscript of $R$ and as an index of summation, I don't understand whether it defines real numbers $R_1,\ldots,R_n$ or what. I'm familiar with notation $f_n=\sum_{i=1}^n$ but $f_i=\sum_{i=1}^n$ is new for me.

So, can anyone explain how I should understand the definition? If I just plug $i=2$ to the equation I can see that $R_2$ looks like a reasonable notation but what is $\sum_{2=1}^n$?

Comment: So in the numerator we have $y_i$ but in the denominator we have $y_k$?

Comment: Sorry... i deleted my former comment by mistake. It was said that you can replace $\sum_i^n$ by $\sum_k^n$ to remove any confusion. In the numerator you therefore have the specific $y_i$, and in the denominator are all $y_k$'s for $k$ running from $1$ to $n$:
$$R_1 = \frac{y_1 - \hat{y}_1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2} \left[ (y_1 - \hat{y}_1)^2 + \dotsb + (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 + \dotsb + (y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2 \right]}}$$

Comment: The summation notation is deceiving you: an expression like "$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$" does not involve "$i$" at all. When you write it out *fully* (*not* as @ocram has just done, which is erroneous because "$i$" now appears free), it depends only on $f$ and $n$. This is the distinction between [free and bound variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples).

Comment: True whuber, thanks. I have always avoided such situations by choosing indexes well, and this was the first time when I read a text having such a notation.

Comment: "residuals" is the normal English term, for future reference.  Has the comment by @whuber on the two different uses of "i" cleared up the question?

Comment: @PeterEllis Yes. I understood that I should first compute the sum expression and then I can use $i$ as it does not appear anymore in the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

That definition was not very carefully written.  It should actually be 
$$
R_i = \frac{y_i-\hat y_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (y_j-\hat y_j)^2}}
$$